# text-alignment=justify for titanium appcelerator application?

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, text-alignment, text-justify

i am using `titanium appcelerator` to develop cross platform application in ios and android.

right now am facing problem with justify the text alignment. i have goggled the things but still no success.

This [links](https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/149692/text-align-justify) saying that titanium does not allow `text-alignment=justify`

but is there any other way to justify the text?any other hack to implement justify text alignment?please help me its been a two weeks but no success for me

Answer (score 1):

As they say, There is not solution! But if you target only Android and your text will be in a label, you can use html tag `<p style="text-align:justify;">Lorem ipsum </p>` but it will not work on iOS